# WARNING: QStandardPaths: error creating runtime directory '/directory/path' (No such file or directory) WARNING: could not determine DPI

Tags: api, qt, warnings, dpi, qstandardpaths

Is it possible to silence these errors? I am creating an application that displays a terminal and runs the napari software, and don't want these warnings to show. Is there any variable I can turn off or silence to prevent these messages from showing up? I was not able to find that in the QStandardPaths documentation. Thank you so much!

WARNING: QStandardPaths: error creating runtime directory '/directory/path' (No such file or directory)
WARNING: could not determine DPI